# Magnific popup is not opening on first click / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, popup

I have implemented magnific popup which uses JavaScript to connect server side. It is working fine from 2nd click, but in 1st click the magnific popup is not loaded as I tested.

code in my jsp file

```
<a href="javascript:test(${data.PKey});" data-mfp-src="#testpop" class="open-popup-link">click here</a>
<span id="promotepop" class="white-popup"></span>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function promote(id){
var url="database.jsp?pkey="+id;
var xmlhttp;
      $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
         type: 'inline',
         overflowY: 'scroll',
         alignTop: 'true',
  });

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
      
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    
  if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4)
        document.getElementById("promotepop").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        {
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

Comment: Very silly to not use $.ajax when you have it. Also do NOT use href="javascript:..." but assign the click handler in jQuery and use preventDefault. Where do you call promote? You need to assign the popup in the onload of the page

Comment: Where are you running the function of `promote`?

Comment: sorry, in javascript the function name is test()
and ahy we do not use href="javascript..."

Comment: can you please tell me how to use $.ajax.. 
what are its importance over the current code??
and changed href="javascript.." to normal, still not getting magnific popup in first click..